# Python in ArcGIS - Lookup values in a dictionary and print corresponding value into a new field

Tags: python, dictionary, arcgis, vlookup

I am very new to python and have been trying for days to work write a function that decodes a field in my attribute table and adds the corresponding value (from the dictionary below) into the blank field. (Similar to a vlookup in excel). So for example when 'e1' shows up in my attribute table look up 'e' in the dictionary, find the corresponding value in the dictionary and print it into a list and then look up '1' and print it into the same list (Blank field has already been added to the attribute table). Then add this list to into a blank field in the attribute table.

Answer (score 1):

Your data structure is not your friend at this point.

You have all this information stacked up in a nested dictionary structure, but you would be better off decoding it first:

```
#!python3

import collections
import itertools

LUC_dict = {
   'estu':'Estuaries',
   'ice':'Ice',
   'lake':'Lake',
   'quar':'Quarries/Mines',
   'rive':'River',
   'town':'Town/Urban',
   'Class':{'1':'Arable (1)',
       '2':'Arable (2)',
       '3':'Arable (3)',
       '4':'Arable (4)',
       '5':'Non Arable (5)',
       '6':'Non Arable (6)',
       '7':'Non Arable (7)',
       '8':'Protected (8)'},
   'Subclass':{'c':'Climiate',
       'e': 'Erosion',
       's': 'Soil',
       'w': 'Wetness'}}

field1_value = {k:v for k,v in LUC_dict.items() if k not in ('Class','Subclass')}
field2_value = collections.defaultdict(str)

classes = LUC_dict['Class']
subclasses = LUC_dict['Subclass']

for c,sc in itertools.product(classes.keys(), subclasses.keys()):
    field1_value[c+sc] = classes[c]
    field2_value[c+sc] = subclasses[sc]


def decode(instr):
    return field1_value[instr], field2_value[instr]

tests = "6e 4s rive 2s estu"

for test in tests.split():
    f1, f2 = decode(test)
    print("{}: [{}, {}]".format(test, f1, f2))
```

The output from this looks like:

```
6e: [Non Arable (6), Erosion]
4s: [Arable (4), Soil]
rive: [River, ]
2s: [Arable (2), Soil]
estu: [Estuaries, ]
```

which I think is what you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Would this do the trick? Tried to model my solution directly after your psuedocode for clarity.

```
def decode_LUC(input_string, LUC_dict): # Changed signature to also accept the dict (keep parameter local to function)
    if not input_string.isalnum(): # Check if alphanumeric
        raise ValueError("Input string is not alphanumeric!")
    elif len(input_string) == 2: # Split if we have len 2
        part1, part2 = input_string[0], input_string[1] # Split into two strings
        return [LUC_dict["Class"][part1], LUC_dict["Subclass"][part2]]
    else: # Else try to directly access dict
        return LUC_dict[input_string]

LUC_dict = {
'estu':'Estuaries',
'ice':'Ice',
'lake':'Lake',
'quar':'Quarries/Mines',
'rive':'River',
'town':'Town/Urban',
'Class':{'1':'Arable (1)',
'2':'Arable (2)',
'3':'Arable (3)',
'4':'Arable (4)',
'5':'Non Arable (5)',
'6':'Non Arable (6)',
'7':'Non Arable (7)',
'8':'Protected (8)'},
'Subclass':{'c':'Climiate',
'e': 'Erosion',
's': 'Soil',
'w': 'Wetness'}}

# If you're in Python3, wrap the print statements with parens
print decode_LUC("6e", LUC_dict) # Prints ['Non Arable (6)', 'Erosion']
print decode_LUC("estu", LUC_dict) # Prints Estuaries
print decode_LUC("e^", LUC_dict) # Raises a value error
```